# При уменьшении .svg теряет качество, и линии плывут

Tags: svg, corel-draw

Проблема такова, есть лого .svg большой размер. Я хочу его уменьшить до нужных размерах в короле, и в итоге он мне уродует лого. Линии кривые. Не пойму как мне уменьшить размер без потери качества.

Comment: Как вариант откройте в блокноте, и поставьте нужные размеры в width="" и height="" у тега svg.

Comment: Интересно..... попробую ! Спасибо !